# How to limit an image size in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, resize

As you can see in http://thefreefallband.com/super in the last post there's an image too big for almost every computer. Is there anyway to pu t a limit to the images in wordpress in width?

If there isn't, how can i resize it via html code without losing the proportion?

Comment: How are you displaying the image? Is it uploaded to your media library, and is it the post featured image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really simple CSS fix would be:

```
.post img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the sizes of images the WP makes automatically when you upload them to the Media Library by going to 'Settings -> Media'. Note that while `Thumnial Size` will crop your image to the exact size you specify, `Medium Size` and `Large Size` will keep the aspect ratio of your image, while resizing it to fit your specified max height/width.

If they are not good for you, you can add you own image size in `functions.php`

```
add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );
```

See the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) for more informaion.

When calling an image, depending on the function your are using, you can specify either one of the defined image sizes, or a maximum height/width (WP will find the closest match if you do this).

Assuming your are using the post featured image -

```
if(has_post_thumbnail( $post_id )) :
    the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );
endif;
```

See the codex for [`has_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail) and [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) for more informaion.